# Cómo saber qué configuraciones aplicar para correr algo descargado de GIT?

Tags: spring-boot, github

Supongo que será una pregunta de completo novato en esto, pero no me aclaro y estoy completamente en un bucle en el que como no consigo ninguna solución, no consigo salir.
Estoy intentando informarme sobre temas de OAuth. Para ello, he buscado y leido bastante primero sobre el tema, y he buscado ejemplos para ejecutar y hacer cambios poco a poco para ir entendiendo el funcionamiento de todo e intentar aplicar lo que he leido.
El problema es que no consigo correr ningún ejemplo descargado de GIT. Cómo sé qué tengo que configurar para que me funcione un proyecto descargado?

Por ejemplo este:
https://github.com/britez/ms-oauth2-rest

O este otro:
https://github.com/arocketman/Spring-oauth2-jpa-example

Hay algún paso que se me escapa entre clonar y lanzar. Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta es: _depende del proyecto_. Cada proyecto se construye/maneja de una forma diferente.... y definitivamente no es una pregunta de git así que le voy a quitar la etiqueta.

Comment: como dice @eftshift0 esto depende de cada proyecto, lo que se debe hacer siempre es leer el archivo README.MD ahí el autor debe/debería colocar las instrucciones de instalación/uso del repositorio, en el segundo enlace en el README hay otro enlace a la documentación para poderlo implementar

Comment: Creo que la pregunta le falta ser mas específica, es muy abierta. Considera editarla y agregar qué problemas tienes al intentar correr un proyecto específico. Coloca los pasos que realizaste y los errores que obtienes